# Cancelling a pending transaction on ETH blockchain

Tags: gas-limit, pending-transactions

I want to cancel a transaction on ETH chain but my hardware wallet does not have an advanced option to set a nonce for tx. Is there any alternative to cancel a tx ?

Comment: you cant cancel a transaction, once you sign it, it is irrevesible

Comment: I posted an answer to the main question. It's an option you can use with https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020394612-How-to-connect-a-Trezor-or-Ledger-Hardware-Wallet